# Passing same x axis label to matplotlib subplots of barplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create subplots of barplots.  matplotlib is funny with labeling the x axis of barplots so you need to pass an index then use the `xticks` function to pass the labels.  I want to create 2 subplots that each have the same x axis labels but with the code below I can only pass the labels onto the last bar plot.  My question is how can I pass the labels to **both** bar plots?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(18,15))

r1 = axes[0].bar(idx, data1, align='center')
axes[0].set_title('title1')

r2 = axes[1].bar(idx, data2, align='center')
axes[1].set_title('title2')

plt.xticks(idx, idx_labels, rotation=45)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.xticks` as all other pyplot commands relate to the currently active axes. Having produced several axes at once via `plt.subplots()`, the last of them is the current axes, and thus the axes for which `plt.xticks` would set the ticks.

You may set the current axes using `plt.sca(axes)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx, data1, data2, idx_labels = [1,2,3], [3,4,2], [2,5,4], list("ABC")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

r1 = axes[0].bar(idx, data1, align='center')
axes[0].set_title('title1')

plt.sca(axes[0])
plt.xticks(idx, idx_labels, rotation=45)

r2 = axes[1].bar(idx, data2, align='center')
axes[1].set_title('title2')

plt.sca(axes[1])
plt.xticks(idx, idx_labels, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

However, when working with subplots, it is often easier to use the object-oriented API of matplotlib instead of the pyplot statemachine. In that case you'd use `ax.set_xticks` and  `ax.set_xticklabels`, where `ax` is the axes for which you want to set some property. This is more intuitive, since it is easily seen from the code which axes it being worked on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx, data1, data2, idx_labels = [1,2,3], [3,4,2], [2,5,4], list("ABC")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

r1 = axes[0].bar(idx, data1, align='center')
axes[0].set_title('title1')

r2 = axes[1].bar(idx, data2, align='center')
axes[1].set_title('title2')

for ax in axes:
    ax.set_xticks(idx)
    ax.set_xticklabels(idx_labels, rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

Comment: So this is why I can't set it using something like `axes[0].set_xticklabels(idx_labels)`?

Comment: You can (and need to) set both, ticks and ticklabels, `axes[0].set_xticks(idx);
    axes[0].set_xticklabels(idx_labels, rotation=45)`.

Comment: So this could also be a way to create subplots with their own unique x axis labels.  thanks for your help!